# Bubble plot with NaN values

Tags: python, matplotlib, nan, colormap, bubble-chart

I have a dataframe like this:

| x | y | height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 5 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 | 100 |
| 4 | 7 | NaN |
| 5 | 6 | NaN |
| 6 | 12 | 500 |

I need to create a bubble plot for x-y with 'height' as the variable for the point sizes (with some other marker when it is NaN).

I'm trying to condition the height variable this way, to no success.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', c='k', s=height)
ax.scatter(x[height==np.nan], y[height==np.nan], marker='^', c='r')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], marker='o', c='k', s=df['height'])

ax.scatter(df.loc[df['height'].isna(), 'x'], df.loc[df['height'].isna(), 'y'],
           marker='^', c='r')
```

[image]